# How can I add to a DataGrid a context menu created from a attached behavior on c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, contextmenu, attachedbehaviors

Basically I have a DataGrid on c# in which i need to create a Context Menu that will be displayed only with the right clic of the mouse. This needs to be done as attached behavior if i'm not wrong to be reused on several datagrids.

Can someone help me with? I'm new with WPF and all this stuff...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By assigning a Context Menu to the ContextMenu property of a DataGrid, the Context Menu will be displayed upon right click - this is the default behavior. I'm assuming that you want something different from this default behavior? Could elaborate more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the context menu in the resources (here at the Window level but you can use a Resources file), then use StaticResource in the Datagrid ContextMenu definition:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <ContextMenu x:Key="DgCtxtMenu" >
    <MenuItem Header="Do stuff"  />
  </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid ContextMenu="{StaticResource DgCtxtMenu}" />
```